# "uncap" a capped MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

is there a way to "uncap" a capped collection? 
Creating a new collection and copy the data isn't an option for me.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, You can convert a non-capped collection to a capped collection using the "convertToCapped" command but there's no way to go the other way.

Your only option is to clone the collection to a non capped one and rename it which obviously involves downtime.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  Is "clone" a MongoDB function, or is that just the general idea of what you'd need to do?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the only option here is to copy collection, remove the old one and rename the new one:

```
$> db.collection_name.copyTo('collection_name2')
$> db.collection_name.isCapped()
true
$> db.collection_name.drop()
$> db.collection_name2.renameCollection('collection_name')
$> db.collection_name.isCapped()
false
```

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. `copyTo` takes a global lock and will block all write operations. If you do it in production, it will take everything down. Instead see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624964/whats-the-fastest-way-to-copy-a-collection-within-the-same-database#33889197