# What's the fastest way to copy a collection within the same database?

Tags: mongodb

I want to copy a collection within the **same** database and give it a 
different name - basically take a snapshot.

What's the best way to do this? Is there a command, or do I have to 
copy each record in turn?

I'm aware of the `cloneCollection` command, but it seems to be for 
copying to another server only.

I'm also aware of `mongoimport` and `mongoexport`, but as I'm doing this via PHP I'd prefer not to make calls out to the shell.

Comment: The correct answer is the one with 230 upvotes.

Comment: `db.myoriginal.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "mycopy" } ])` This is the faster than accepted answer.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I am unable to unaccept the answer, but it may have been correct in 2012. $out requires v2.6 of MongoDB which was not released until 2014.

Comment: @DanielViglione the votes count always changes. the correct answer is of `jschildgen` :D

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have a few options, but the fastest is:

```
mongodump -d db -c sourcecollection 
mongorestore -d db -c targetcollection --dir=dump/<db>/<sourcecollection.bson>
```

or

```
mongoexport -d db -c sourcecollection | mongoimport -d db -c targetcollection --drop
```

or in php:

```
`mongoexport -d db -c sourcecollection | mongoimport -d db -c targetcollection --drop`;
```

after that you have

```
mongo db < script.js
```

where, as shown in the [mongo docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Developer+FAQ#DeveloperFAQ-HowdoIcopyallobjectsfromonedatabasecollectiontoanother?), script.js contains something like:

```
db.myoriginal.find().forEach( function(x){db.mycopy.insert(x)} );
```

The slowest (by an order of magnitude or more) way to copy a collection will be to use the native php driver - simply because of moving information around. But you could issue the above mongo query if you absolutely want to avoid cli calls using the [db execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) function.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using your first option, but was hoping there was a command I could simply call so I don't need to call the shell from PHP.

Comment: I may try the script approach using  http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php

Comment: Using a dumb mapReduce (self-mapping, no reducing), measures between mongoexpor and script.js solutions for me...

Comment: Mongodump | mongorestore should be faster than export|import since it doesn't have to deserialize the binary format to json or csv.

Comment: @CodyA.Ray it's a long time since I've used mongo, this answer was provided based on observed performance at the time (now 4+ years ago). Please update the answer if you are able to demonstrate a better method.

Comment: How to preserve indexes during copying to targetcollection?

Answer (score 340):

```
> use yourDatabaseName
> db.myOriginal.aggregate([{$out: "myCopy"}])
```

It is a lot faster than doing many inserts in a `forEach` loop.

Comment: I just tried this, it's very fast. You need to include a match operator in there too: db.stream.aggregate([{$match: {}},{$out: "s2"}]); On my powerbook it took 2 seconds to copy 50,000 documents each a few KB

Comment: 12GB of data in 1-2 minutes on a i5 PC. And the best part : it's non-blocking

Comment: pls notice that target can't be a *capped collection*.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Be aware that the indices will be missing

Comment: Doesn't work for versions older than 2.6 (my case). The first answer worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore duplicate key error with this approach? I'm trying to duplicate a large collection and apply new unique compound key. Any ideas?

Comment: How can I include the index to the new collection with this method?

Comment: @aandis From what I know, you will need to add the indices in a subsequent step if you were to follow this method.
This would help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150231/mongodb-how-to-copy-index-definitions-from-one-collection-to-another

Comment: Not sure why, but I needed to add a `.to_a` or `.count` at the end to get this to work.

Comment: Why to insert { $match: {} }?. Actually it works without it for me (I have 4.2).

Comment: @StefanRogin how much RAM do you have? For me, memory usage increase is ~5 times greater than the collection being copied.

Comment: @НикитаМихайлов I had 16 or 32 GB

Comment: That said I don't remember at the time any issues with memory.

Comment: 4.5 million documents copied with in 40 secs.

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO, fast and simple, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Cannot copy to sharded collection

Comment: I don't understand, I am using this approach on a table with `STORAGE SIZE: 912.98MB`, `LOGICAL DATA SIZE: 3.35GB`, `TOTAL DOCUMENTS: 8535855`, `INDEXES TOTAL SIZE: 332.62MB` in MongoDB Atlas and it takes 5 minutes. Meanwhile, others in this thread are copying 12GB of data in 1-2 minutes, 5 years ago?

Answer (score 17):

For versions less than 3.0, you can use [copyTo()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) for **experimental** uses (**never use on Production**, as it [blocks write operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/#behavior)):

```
db.source.copyTo("target");
```

& if `"target"` doesn't exist, it will be created

Comment: Upto v2.6.3 `copyTo()` will block all operations on the `mongod` instance.
From documentation:
> Because copyTo() uses eval internally, the copy operations will block all other operations on the mongod instance.

Comment: @YogeshMangaj thanks for the note, I updated the answer to be easily visible for everybody.

Comment: Deprecated since version 3.0.

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. As explained in the docs, this will block all write operations.

Comment: @lbolla I already mentioned this in the answer itself months ago :D

Comment: In addition to blocking and being deprecated It's also insanely slow 

Comment: then whats the modern way to copy if this is deprecated?

Comment: @theprogrammer, the best way is the other answer posted here (just above my answer) by yoooshi, which uses aggregation.

Answer (score 4):

***First option: using `mongodump`***

1. Get a dump from `source_collection`

   ```
   $ mongodump -d db -c source_collection
   ```
2. Restore to `target_collection` collection from the dump

   ```
   $ mongorestore -d db -c target_collection dir=dump/db_name/source_collection.bson
   ```

***Second option: `$out` aggregation step***

1. Run an aggregate command on `source_collection`

   ```
   > db.source_collection.aggregate([
       {$match: {emailAddress: "apitester@mailinator.com"}},
       {$out: "target_collection"}
     ])
   ```

***Third option (slowest): iterate and copy all documents***

1. Run a loop through all documents of `source_collection`, inserting them into `target_collection`

   ```
   > db.source_collection.find().forEach((doc) => {
       db.target_collection.insert(doc);
     })
     && print("Copy completed!");
   ```

Comment: Which one of the first two options is faster?

Comment: The second option is the fastest, because everything happens inside MongoDB and the data never leaves the server. You don't need local disk space and won't use the network for data. The downside, it won't preserve indices. The first option is decent, but still requires the whole data to be transferred outside the server and then transmitted back. You have to account for disk space and bandwidth. The third option is very slow because it processes inserts individually and transmits each document over the network. It doesn't require local disk space, though.

Comment: Agreed with @vi

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the answer, but I don't have enough rep to post a comment.

The accepted answer has a typo, it should be:

```
$ mongorestore -d db -c target_collection --dir=dump/db_name/source_collection.bson
```

note the -- before dir that isn't present in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AD7six 1st solution, if you use mongoexport / import be sure about your collection data types and mongo configuration, as explained here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Comment: Please  clarify/state what you wish to point out. Mongoimport and mongoexport use the same format, there's nothing to configure,  and no risk of data mutating afaik.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation in python (pymongo):

```
def copy_collection(client, from_db, from_coll, to_db=None, to_coll=None):
    to_db = from_db if to_db is None else to_db
    to_coll = from_coll if to_coll is None else to_coll
    assert (to_db != from_db or to_coll != from_coll), "Copy Error: Source and destination can't be same!"
    documents = client[from_db][from_coll].find()
    client[to_db][to_coll].insert_many([d for d in documents])
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that with this query :-

Suppose you have collection name **data1** and you want to make new collection **data2** with same indexes or want to delete or add some index you can do this by using this query.

**data1**  have indexes
*| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Age | Occupation*

and you want to make new collection **data2**
*| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Age | Occupation | Date*

*Query It took very less time in my case (speed depend on amount of data)*

```
var cursor = db.data1.find();
var data = [];
while(cursor.hasNest()){
    var a = cursor.next();
    data.push({
        "FirstName" : a.FirstName,
        "MiddleName" : a.MiddleName,
        "LastName" : a.LastName,
        "Age" : a.Age,
        "Occupation" : a.Occupation,
        "Date" : new Date()
    });
}

db.data2.insertMany(data)
```

**----- UPDATE -----**

As this will build in memory array so for large set of data memory consumption will be high, so to solve this problem what one can do is define a flag and after some record let say 1000 you can insert the current data in collection and empty that array.

Comment: Yes, it saves time by accumulating documents and inserting in bulk, but this will create a brand new collection, without any indices. Also, for large collections, building an in-memory array with the documents may be too much memory footprint for the machine operating the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way is [db.collection.copyTo()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/).

Note that it is deprecated since version 3.0.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the copyDatabase function in the mongo shell:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/copy-databases-between-instances/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.