# How to copy one table of mongodb to another table of mongodb at different location location?

Tags: mongodb

i have 2 mongodb database,

1 in in my local host

and 2nd in in other computer

```
here Myinfo <= database name

CustomerDetails <= table Name

let's see 1st : `Localhost / Myinfo / CustomerDetails`
```

i want to copy all collection of CustomerDetails to another db at :

```
let's say 2nd : `192.168.1.10/ Myinfo / CustomerDetails
```

how can i do that?
`
Note: i do not want to copy whole db , just only one table!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to copy a collection within the same database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624964/whats-the-fastest-way-to-copy-a-collection-within-the-same-database) (it's the same answer whether a different db or not). Btw mongo doesn't have tables :) it has _collections_.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method from the target host, in the shell:

```
> use MyInfo
> db.cloneDatabase("origin hostname/ or IP")
```