# MongoDB How to copy index definitions from one collection to another?

Tags: mongodb

I know there's a way to do db.collection.getIndexes() Which will list all the indexes defined for a collection. Is there a way to copy and create those index definitions to another collection?

There's a lot of them and I don't want to do them one by one.

regarding the duplicated question comment: I do not wish to copy a collection. I wish to export indexes in a format that I can apply to another collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a collection from one database to another in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb)

Comment: Get the indexes in valid JSON, then copy-paste: `JSON.stringify(db.clients.getIndexes())`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For example I have one existing **user** collection with indexes *_id_*, *name_1*, *email_1* and *website_1*

Then I have another collection called **usertest**, I want to copy indexes from **user** collection to **usertest** collection. The following commands works for this scenario:

1. Copy both index key and index options

   ```
   var indexes = db.user.getIndexes();

   indexes.forEach(function(index){
       delete index.v;
       delete index.ns;
       var key = index.key;
       delete index.key
       var options = [];
       for (var option in index) {
           options.push(index[option]);
       }
      db.usertest.createIndex(key, options);
   });
   ```
2. Copy index key only (batch processing)

   ```
   var indexKeys = db.user.getIndexKeys();
   db.usertest.createIndexes(indexKeys);
   ```

Hope this will be helpful. Here's the doc: [createIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

Comment: I saw that db.collection.getIndexKeys() method. The problem I immediately saw, was that it didn't list the options for the indexes, right?
So an unique index on the user collection will not be unique on the usertest collection :/

Comment: You know of any  parameter to be passed to the getIndexKeys() method so it returns index options? I can't find the method on the docs.

Comment: There's no such param as far as I know. I've updated my code to copy the index options. Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: the `'option'` in `options.push(index['option']);` should be without quotes, right? We want the variable, not the string 'option'? But also, this might throw `"Index options that are supplied in array form may only specify three values: name, unique, dropDups"`, so it might be better to send the `options` as an object, so line 7: `var options = {}` and then line 10: `options[option] = index[option]`

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 14):

To do this directly in MongoDB do the following,

The following command will generate mongo DB queries for existing indexes of all collections,

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(col) {
    var indexes = db[col].getIndexes();
    indexes.forEach(function (c) {
        var fields = '', result = '', options = {};
        for (var i in c) {
            if (i == 'key') {
                fields = c[i];
            } else if (i == 'name' && c[i] == '_id_') {
                return;
            } else if (i != 'name' && i != 'v' && i != 'ns') {
                options[i] = c[i];
            }
        }
        var fields = JSON.stringify(fields);
        var options = JSON.stringify(options);
        if (options == '{}') {
            result = "db." + col + ".createIndex(" + fields + "); ";
        } else {
            result = "db." + col + ".createIndex(" + fields + ", " + options + "); ";
        }
        result = result
            .replace(/{"floatApprox":-1,"top":-1,"bottom":-1}/ig, '-1')
            .replace(/{"floatApprox":(-?\d+)}/ig, '$1')
            .replace(/\{"\$numberLong":"(-?\d+)"\}/ig, '$1');
        print(result);
    });
});
```

The above command will output something like the following, based on the amount of collection you have

```
db.User.createIndex({"createdAt":-1}, {"background":true}); 

db.User.createIndex({"updatedAt":-1}, {"background":true}); 

db.Login.createIndex({"loginDate":-1}, {"background":true});
```

So after executing this, copy the MongoDB queries that are generated above to create the indexes to the new collection, Change the collection name in that then execute it.

For eg: to copy all indexes belonging to the User collection to the UserNew collection, I will rename the query's old collection name to new like the following and execute it, that is it, now you have all the indexes copied to a new collection from the old one.

```
db.UserNew.createIndex({"createdAt":-1}, {"background":true}); 

db.UserNew.createIndex({"updatedAt":-1}, {"background":true});
```

Credits: http://aleksandrmaiorov.com/2019/04/29/mongo-how-to-copy-indexes-from-one-database-to-another/

Comment: link to the credit source no longer works. however this worked quite well as i need to copy indices from a source cluster to a target cluster.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the answer from Rocky and Bloke which helped me a lot
here is the consolidated version as suggested by Bloke.
and in PRODUCTION. we would like to make sure the background: true 
is used to avoid slave halt query when indexes creation replicated.

```
var indexes = db.user.getIndexes();
// we skipped the __id__ indexes and set the default background: true option
indexes.forEach(function(index){
    if(index.name =='_id_'){
     print("we are skip the _id_ index")
    }else{
    delete index.v;
    delete index.ns;
    var key = index.key;
    delete index.key
    var options = {};
    for (var option in index) {
        options[option] = index[option]
    }
    options['background'] = true;
    printjson(key);
    printjson(options);
    db.usertest.createIndex(key, options);

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rocky Li's answer was helpful but did not create the index options properly at the time of writing (It gathered the option values but not the keys). The following modification worked for me:

```
var indexes = db.user.getIndexes();

indexes.forEach(function(index){
    delete index.v;
    delete index.ns;
    var key = index.key;
    delete index.key

    // uncomment if you want to ensure creation is in background
    //if(!('background' in index))
        //index['background'] = true;

   db.user.createIndex(key, index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Copy all indexes from one database another database**

```
 use firstDbName;
 var indexKeyArray = [];
 db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
 var indexKeys = db[collection].getIndexKeys();
 var base = {};
 base["name"] = collection;
 base["indices"] = indexKeys
 indexKeyArray.push(base);
});
#printjson(indexKeyArray);
use destinationDbName;
indexKeyArray.forEach(function(data) {
  db[data.name].createIndexes(data.indices);
});
```