# Clone a mongodb collection from within Rails Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am trying to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33889197/2399861) in rails, using the `collection aggregate method`, to clone an entire collection within the same database.

In mongo shell, this works perfectly, and a cloned collection is created successfully:

`db.source_collection.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "target_collection" } ])`

The `rails`-`mongoid` alternate, according to my research, should be this, which runs without errors:

```
SourceCollection.collection.aggregate({"$match" => {},  "$out" => "target_collection"})
#<Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation:0x000000055bced0 @view=#<Mongo::Collection::View:0x44951600 namespace='DB_dev.source_collection' @filter={} @options={}>, @pipeline={"$match"=>{}, "$out"=>"target_collection"}, @options={}>
```

I also tried with an array

```
SourceCollection.collection.aggregate([{"$match" => {}},  {"$out" => "target_collection"}])
#<Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation:0x000000054936d0 @view=#<Mongo::Collection::View:0x44342320 namespace='DB_dev.source_collection' @filter={} @options={}>, @pipeline=[{"$match"=>{}}, {"$out"=>"target_collection"}], @options={}>
```

**UPDATE**

This simplest syntax also works in Mongo console:

`db.source_collection.aggregate( { $out: "target_collection" } )`

But the respective syntax does not seem to work in Ruby:

```
SourceCollection.collection.aggregate({"$out" => "target_collection"})
```

Unfortunately, although there are no errors, the collection is not created.

Any clues as to the way I can make this happen?
Mongo gem version 2.5.3

**Update2**

Apparently $out is not considered in the pipeline, thus rendering the aggregation invalid.

This can be fixed with code... I am looking for a module/class/method override, as contacting mongodb issue tracking system for a change request might not be as quick..

**UPDATE - FINAL**

This issue has been **solved**, by help of Thomas R. Koll (thank you).

I add an update to post the response I got from the ticketing service of MongoDB, which pretty much describes Thomas's solution.

> The reason you're not seeing the results without `count` is that the
>   `aggregate` method returns a lazy cursor; that is, the query does not
>   execute until the return value of `aggregate` is iterated over.
>   Calling `count` is one way to do this. This is the same behavior
>   you'll see if you call `find` or if you call `aggregate` without
>   specifying `$out`; the difference is that `$out` has an side-effect
>   beyond just returning the results, so it's more obvious when exactly
>   it occurs.

Comment: Whatever the answer, it won't have anything to do with mongoid as that is just a data mapper on top of the ruby mongo gem/driver. mongoid doesn't provide the `aggregate` method, only the mongo gem does that.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll You are right, of course. I have realized that, I just forgot to remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, and I have to explain a few thigs:

This returns a Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation object, it won't send a query to the database

```
User.collection.aggregate({"$out": "target_collection"})
```

Only when you call a method like `count` or `to_a` on the aggregation object it will be sent to the server, but if you pass a hash you'll get an error, so the pipeline has to be an array of hashes to work

```
User.collection.aggregate([{"$out": "target_collection"}]).count
```

Comment: Mister, you are a saint :). This is a very intuitive workaround that actually works. Thank you so much!

Comment: With 9 years of mongodb exp I gotta know a bit, right :) Greetings to Greece, I miss it.

Comment: Greetings from Greece to you too. I am only a couple of mongo-months old, but I get the feeling that I will grow mongold as well :). Cheers, keep up the good work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Also, I need to know how to do the equivalent of db.target_collection.aggregate in MongoID

Comment: @WylliamJudd Mongoid doesn't have aggregate, only the underlying `Mongo` module has. You probably want to read the documentation first, try out the examples in there and open a new question if you still have unanswered points https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: Oh I see. Still the mongodb docs won't help me, I'll need documentation on the Mongo Ruby on Rails module.

Comment: please  open a new question @WylliamJudd